# Clone folders from Git Repository - TFS using Python 2.7 without installing Windows Git

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, api, tfs

I'm working on a Python script (2.7) which will clone specific folders from a Git Online TFS Repository. Looking to make it work only using Python packages (as needed) or through Rest API as provided in https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests

Trying to avoid installing Git in the machine, as there will not be any commits from the machine, also it will be OS independent this way. Just need to clone latest code from Git and execute it. No challenges in anyway w.r.t access privileges (assume I have full access to the TFS repository and its contents). Any pointers towards a solution would be gladly accepted :)

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

The way that without OS independent is the REST API, however there isn’t the REST API in TFS/VSTS to clone TFS/VSTS repository to local machine.

If you just need to get the files, you can use this REST API below to download the files (compressed in a zip file): [Zip a folder](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/items#zip-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pygit2](http://www.pygit2.org/) to clone Git repository via Python.